# How do I remove the italic style from dfn tag?

Tags: html

How do I remove the italic style from dfn tag?

Example:

```
<dfn title="Go to the home page">Home</dfn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following CSS:

```
dfn {font-style: normal;}
```